# Как использовать один метод для трех переменных?

Tags: java, android

В общем вот есть такой метод, который считает среднее значение за 2 секунды времени(Но это не так важно)

```
private Map<Long, Double> mapAxisX = new HashMap<>();
private int countAxisXTimes;
private double countAxisXSum;

@Override public double calculateMiddleVarOfAxisX(double axisX) {
    long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
    countAxisXTimes++;
    countAxisXSum += axisX;

    mapAxisX.put(current, axisX);

    if (mapAxisX.size() == 1) {
        return axisX;
    }

    Iterator iterator = mapAxisX.entrySet().iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<Long, Double> point = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
        long pointTime = point.getKey();
        long difference = current - pointTime;

        if (difference > 2000) {
            double val = point.getValue();
            countAxisXTimes--;
            countAxisXSum -= val;
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }

    double result = countAxisXSum / countAxisXTimes;
    //Logger.logGeneral(String.valueOf(result) + " size : " + mapAxisX.size());

    return result;
}
```

вызываю я его вот так

```
axisX = presenter.calculateMiddleVarOfAxisX(event.values[0]);
```

И он работает нормально, но вот если мне нужно посчитать среднее значение для другой оси(допустим `axisX`) то мне нужно полностью продублировать этот метод так как если его вызывать одновременно и для другой переменной , значения будут считаться с одном методе сразу для двух переменных вот так

```
axisX = presenter.calculateMiddleVarOfAxisX(event.values[0]);
axisY = presenter.calculateMiddleVarOfAxisX(event.values[1]);
```

и конечно получается не то что нужно.

Я подумал сначала, что можно передавать `mapAxisX`, `countAxisXTimes` и `countAxisXSum` как параметры, но тогда все усложняется и мне нужно их возвращать, в общем криво будет...

Мне так думается, что нужно создать пул и с помощью `Callable` возвращать значения, но тогда тоже не совсем понятно как сделать такую имплементацию, так как эти методы

```
axisX = presenter.calculateMiddleVarOfAxisX(event.values[0]);
axisY = presenter.calculateMiddleVarOfAxisX(event.values[1]);
```

вызываются в `callback`-e от сенсора, с частотой до 50 раз в секунду...

В общем подскажите как поступить, не хочется дублировать код...

Comment: Вынесите метод вместе с полями нужными для расчета в  отдельный класс. Для каждого расчета создайте экземпляр этого класса и вызывайте метод нужного вам экземпляра. То есть отдельный экземпляр для каждой оси. В результате поля хранящие значения важные для расчета не будут пересекаться.

Comment: И почему мне захотелось все усложнить... Да все реботает

Comment: Перенесу комментарий в ответ, раз никто ничего лучше не предложил и вас мой ответ утроил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вынесите метод вместе с полями нужными для расчета в отдельный класс. Для каждого расчета создайте экземпляр этого класса и вызывайте метод нужного вам экземпляра. То есть отдельный экземпляр для каждой оси. В результате поля хранящие значения важные для расчета не будут пересекаться